# Updating user avatar using PHP

Tags: php

The issue I am facing is this:

`Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\littletodoapp\profile.php on line 56`

```
$folder = "uploads/";
$upload_image = $folder . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
if(isset($_POST["updatePhoto"])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $upload_image)) {

        $checkImage = "SELECT imageID FROM photos WHERE userID = :userID";
        $checkImage = $pdo->prepare($checkImage);
        $checkImage->bindParam(':userID',$_SESSION['user_id']);
        $checkImage->execute();

        $row = $checkImage->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($checkImage->rowCount() > 0) {
            $checkImage = "UPDATE photos SET (imageID, userID) VALUES (:uploadImage, :userID WHERE userID = :userID";
        $checkImage = $pdo->prepare($checkImage);
        $checkImage->bindParam(':uploadImage',$upload_image);
            $checkImage->bindParam(':userID',$_SESSION['user_id']);
            $checkImage->execute();
        }  else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
```

I am not 100% why I am getting this error when I first load `profile.php.` Of course if I attempt to submit a new image, the error goes away but subsequently my new image is not uploaded and I of course see the error being echo'd.

Can someone please help point me in the right direction? I am quite positive I am overlooking something small.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you mind to point out which line number 56 is? Thanks.

Comment: If you call the same script before and after the upload then obviously the line holding `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` with throw a _warning_ (which is not an error), since before the upload that variable is not set.

Comment: You are correct. I moved the code a bit. Warning is gone. Fixed one other issue with the code and now its working like a champ! If you want to submit your response as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Sure, added an answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reads like you call the same script before and after the upload. Though that causes a number of potential issues it is a wide spread habit especially in beginners tutorials. For the future you should separate those things: presenting and processing the form are two separate things, so keep the code separate. That prevents such issues and makes the code much easier to read.

However in your current situation this means that probably the line holding `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` will throw a warning (which is not an error!), since before the upload that variable is not (yet) set. It will only exist in the script run that processes an uploaded file, so when a `HTTP POST` request is performed.